# Laravel and @if statement inside javascript object literal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel-5, object-literal

I hope i wrote it correctly, as i remember when you have an array options in javascript these are called object literals. I have a problem i can't find how to use @if statement in object literal. 
I have a small site and everything is located inside welcome.blade.php template so i don't have separate javascript file, the function that i use is just at the bottom of the template inside  tags. So here is the whole function that i have

```
    <script>
        var employees = [
            @foreach ($workers->chunk(20) as $chunk)
            [
                @foreach ($chunk as $worker)
                    {
                        innerHTML:'<div class="container-fluid full-height"><div class="row full-height"><div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 full-height"><div class="person-info"><blockquote><h1>{{ $worker->first_name }} {{ $worker->last_name }}</h1>{{{ $worker->function !== '') ? <footer>{{ $worker->function }}</footer> : '' }}}</blockquote></div></div><div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 full-height"><div class="person-photo"><img class="img-responsive" src="thumbs/{{ $worker->image }}" /></div></div></div></div>',
                        src:"thumbs/{{ $worker->thumbnail }}"
                    },
                @endforeach
            ],
            @endforeach
        ]
    </script>
```

As you can see i need to get all the info from `$workers` inside `innerHTML` and  that should be output as html content, but as some fields will be empty in database  so i need to write @if statement if those fields are not empty to display some code

```
{{{ $worker->function !== '') ? '<footer>{{ $worker->function }}</footer>' :  '' }}}
```

But i can't get it how to get the if statement inside `innerHTML` content to work.

EDIT: The closest that i got it working is like this:

```
'{{ $worker->function ? "<footer>  $worker->function  </footer>" : "" }}' +
```

But this just renders the output completely with `<footer>` so now i have like

John Doe `<footer>` Quality manager `</footer>`

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
<script>
var employees = [
    @foreach ($workers->chunk(20) as $chunk)
    [
        @foreach ($chunk as $worker)
            {
                innerHTML:'<div class="container-fluid full-height">'
                             +'<div class="row full-height">'
                                 +'<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 full-height">'
                                    +'<div class="person-info">'
                                        +'<blockquote>'
                                           +'<h1>' {{ $worker->first_name }} {{ $worker->last_name }} +'</h1>'
                                              @if($worker->function != '') 
                                                +'<footer>' {{ $worker->function }} +'</footer>'
                                              @endif
                                        +'</blockquote>'
                                    +'</div>'
                                +'</div>'
                               +'<div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 full-height">'
                                   +'<div class="person-photo">'
                                      +'<img class="img-responsive" src="thumbs/{{ $worker->image }}" />'
                                   +'</div>'
                               +'</div>'
                             +'</div>'
                          +'</div>',
                src:"thumbs/{{ $worker->thumbnail }}"
            },
        @endforeach
    ],
    @endforeach
]
</script>
```

Comment: Nope, this doesn't work, as soon as you make new line the code breaks, so we have to escape it or use + on every new line, but anyway when it comes to @if it just skips that part and output <footer> anyway.

Comment: Yes i mean `@if` does not work, when i test the code it outputs <footer> like the `@if` does not exists.